# why " 'static' may not be used when defining (as opposed to declaring) a static data member"?

Tags: c++, static

I was looking up ways to initialize static map in C++ and found this code:

```
struct A{
static map<int,int> create_map()
    {
      map<int,int> m;
      m[1] = 2;
      m[3] = 4;
      m[5] = 6;
      return m;
    }
static const map<int,int> myMap;

};

const map<int,int> A:: myMap =  A::create_map();
```

However, if I change the last line to

```
const static map<int,int> A:: myMap =  A::create_map();
```

Compiler complaints: 'static' may not be used when defining (as opposed to declaring) a static data member" ?

I wonder why? What's the logic or reasoning behind this ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
static int    a = 0; // grandfathered and still useful, provides static *LINKAGE*
                     // and static STORAGE DURATION
static int X::a = 0; // confusing and illegal, is it static LINKAGE
                     // or static STORAGE DURATION
                     // or static MEMBERSHIP?
```

`static` already had a meaning (in C) when used on a variable definition.  It would be very surprising for C programmers learning C++ to find that meaning was changed sometimes, but not always.

So the new meaning (static membership) is only active inside the class definition (where C didn't allow the `static` keyword).

Answer (score 4):

It's no different than

```
struct A
{
   static int x;
}

int A::x;         //legal
static int A::x;  //illegal
```

Everything else is just more keywords thrown at this minimal, conceptually identical, example. A `static` member can only be declared `static` inside the class definition.

The

```
const map<int,int> A:: myMap =  A::create_map();
```

outside the class is just a definition of the `static` member `A::myMap`. The extra `static` makes no sense there.

The reasoning behind this is probably to avoid confusion - a `static` free variable is kind of a "private" variable (to a translation unit). A member `static` is the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

Declaring a class member `static` means it is shared between all objects of this class.

When you add `static` to a variable definition outside of a class, it means this variable has file scope and is not visible outside this file.

If it would be allowed to

```
const static map<int,int> A:: myMap =  A::create_map();
```

this would mean, you have a static member variable, which is not visible outside of this file. This just doesn't make sense.

Comment: or else it would mean static membership, which would be inconsistent.

Comment: @BenVoigt unlikely, static for membership there is redundant - you cannot define non-static members this way.

Comment: @Slava: Absolutely true, it'd be inconsistent and redundant, so two good reasons to forbid it.  But I don't think the question was thinking of static linkage.