# Array definition in template classes

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have generated config files with arrays of data (some const static, some mutable) and accessor methods. The problem is that now one of the data types is going to be templated, but I simply cannot get the compiler to accept it.

The templated type is a non-pod, but default constructible.

The definitions used bo be in the cpp file, but as I don't know the templated type while the code is being generated, I cannot do that anymore.

I.e. I would like something like the following (even better if I could but definitions outside the header)

```
template<typename T>
class LargeConfig :
{
public:
    // methods
private:
    static const POD1 POD_ONES[];
    T ManyTs[];
};

template<typename T>
static const POD1 LargeConfig<T>::POD_ONES[] =
{
   { 0U, 1U}, // instance 1
   { 1U, 1U}, // instance 2
   ...
};

template<typename T>
T LargeConfig<T>::ManyTs[] =
{
   T(), // instance 1
   T(), // instance 2
   ...
};
```

Currently I get "*a storage class may not be specified here*" for the **POD_ONES** definition and "*a nonstatic data member may not be defined outside its class*" for the **ManyTs**.

But surely there must be some way to create templated non-trivial arrays in a class in c++? So far I have only found examples where the template type is an integer type.

Comment: Is `POD1` in scope?  I can't get an error as long as it is defined.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Hm. True thanks. While changing the code, I made one member of the static POD struct const. Apparently that caused my embedded compiler to treat it as non-POD and gave the error message above. Without the const member the POD_ONES part works.

Answer (score 1):

First, `ManyTs` is not declared `static`, hence the error about a `nonstatic data member defined outside of class`.

Then, don't put the keyword `static` when you define your `static` member:

```
template<typename T>
class LargeConfig
{
public:
    // methods
private:
    static const POD1 POD_ONES[];
    static T ManyTs[];
};

template<typename T>
const POD1 LargeConfig<T>::POD_ONES[] =
{
   { 0U, 1U}, // instance 1
   { 1U, 1U}, // instance 2
};

template<typename T>
T LargeConfig<T>::ManyTs[] =
{
   T(), // instance 1
   T() // instance 2
};
```

I compiled a [<kbd>sample demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8e67eb1cc7343c9) (setting your `static` data members public to get quick access to them)

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by yourself, you have 2 issues, let me start with the second one.

The `ManyTs` is defined as a regular member of LargeConfig, this means that it should be initialized in the constructor of your class. An example:

```
template<typename T>
LargeConfig<T>::LargeConfig()
: ManyTs
    { T(), // instance 1
      T(), // instance 2
      ...
    }
{}
```

The first issue is harder to guess for, as I managed to compile it with following definition of POD1

```
struct POD1
{
    POD1(unsigned, unsigned);
    unsigned _1{};
    unsigned _2{};
};
```

I suspect that you either don't include the class or something else is going wrong with this class, though, as we can't see it, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to compile your code here (g++ 5.4) I got a syntax error at line 7. Correcting that we get:

```
templates.cpp:16:44: error: ‘static’ may not be used when defining (as opposed to declaring) a static data member [-fpermissive]
 static const POD1 LargeConfig<T>::POD_ONES[] =
                                            ^
templates.cpp:23:26: error: ‘T LargeConfig<T>::ManyTs []’ is not a static data member of ‘class LargeConfig<T>’
 T LargeConfig<T>::ManyTs[] =
                          ^
templates.cpp:23:26: error: template definition of non-template ‘T LargeConfig<T>::ManyTs []’
```

The first message is related to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235161/why-static-may-not-be-used-when-defining-as-opposed-to-declaring-a-static/15235268). You cannot use static to define data types, only for declaring.

The last error was corrected by simple making the `ManyTs` member static.

The code then becomes something like this:

```
class POD1 {

};

template<typename T>
class LargeConfig
{
public:
    // methods
private:
    static const POD1 POD_ONES[];
    static T ManyTs[];
    T ManyTsAgain[10];
};

template<typename T>
const POD1 LargeConfig<T>::POD_ONES[] =
{
   { 0U, 1U}, // instance 1
   { 1U, 1U}, // instance 2
};

template<typename T>
T LargeConfig<T>::ManyTs[] =
{
   T(), // instance 1
   T(), // instance 2
};

int main() {
    LargeConfig<int> obj1;
    LargeConfig<POD1> obj2;

    return 0;
}
```